# Currying functions in categories where products and tensord products differ

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

In closed monoidal category we have
$$
\text{Hom}(X \otimes Y, Z) \cong \text{Hom}(X,[Y,Z])
$$
This way we can curry a function of two arguments. In many categories, the tensor product and product(as a limit) coincide, especially in $\mathbf{Set}$ where both products are just a cartesian product.

However, those two products do not always coincide, for example in category of vector spaces. Therefore, we cannot curry addition. More generally, in many F-algebras we have an operation $X \times X \rightarrow X$, that cannot be curried if tensor and normal product are not the same.

However in the case of vector spaces, we can forget some structure and obtain affine spaces where the tensor product work a bit differently. In particular, there is a map $p: X\otimes Y \rightarrow X\times Y$ such that $i \circ p = \text{id}$, where $i$ is the injection $i: X\times Y \rightarrow X\otimes Y$.

If I got it right, this map $p$ really exist only for tensor product in category of affine spaces and does not exist in category of vector spaces.

By composing this $p$ with addition, we can curry addition. The result is an affine map but that is to be expected.

I would be interested if this relation between vector and affine spaces is an instance of a more general idea? Maybe isn't there some construction which would take a F-algebra, forget some structure and obtain a category where we can curry operations?(probably with the above construction with $p$)

Comment: In general $\times$ and $\otimes$ have nothing to do with eachother and you might be able to curry one and not the other. In vector spaces you can curry $\otimes$ and not $\times$, in $\mathbf{Set}$ if you define $\otimes$ as the coproduct (which is indeed a tensor product in the sense of symmetric monoidal categories) then you can curry $\times$ but not $\otimes$ : there's really no connection in general.

Comment: Does a coproduct in Set give you a closed monoidal category?

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying : a closed structure wrt  $\otimes$ and a closed structure wrt $\times$ have nothing to do with one another, they can be unrelated, in both directions.

Comment: Of course, in general those two products are not related. But I gave an example of affine spaces where there is some relation and I'm interested if this is a more general phenomena for a certain class of categories(maybe for abelian categories?)

Comment: Then I don't understand your question (but that's also because I don't know what you mean by the tensor product of affine spaces)

Comment: I would define tensor product through universal as in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property but instead of bilinear map take biaffine map. If I have not done a mistake then an affine tensor product between $n$ and $m$ dimensional spaces is should be $mn+n+m$ dimensional space, vector tensor product give you only $mn$ dimensional space.

Comment: I think I have found what I was looking for, the term is semi cartesian monoidal category https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicartesian+monoidal+category also called monoidal category with projections, see https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/08/monoidal_categories_with_proje.html the projection is exactly the function $p$ I have defined above.